# Custom ASPX page in List Defination SetupPath

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have made a User Control and registered it to an ASPX page and that ASPX page is being deployed to the Lists/Forms/CustomPage.aspx and User Control is placed in Controltemplates/Forms folder

Now I have made a list defination in which I am trying to connect the aspx page in place of the newform -> SetupPath attribute as follows:

```
<Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="Lists\Forms\CustomPage.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main"  />
```

but I am getting the following error. Let me know

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': The system
>   cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

Thanks.

Comment: Where are the errors?

Comment: Its added now, please see.

Comment: Follow this guide http://kvdlinden.blogspot.se/2011/02/how-to-customize-sharepoint-list-using.html to create the correct VS project structure. The error lays in where you provision your custom form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by changing this line in schema of list defination

```
<Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="Lists\Forms\CustomPage.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main"  />
```

to

```
<Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="Features\$SharePoint.Feature.DeploymentPath$\ListForm\CustomPage.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main"  />
```

where ListForm is my module name.